# How to find blank value from all member of class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have third party object which contain so many member with integer, string and Boolean. I want to update that record whose value is not null or blank

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to achieve what you want:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim obj As Test = new Test()

    Dim type As Type = GetType(Test)
    Dim info As PropertyInfo() = type.GetProperties()
    For Each propertyInfo As PropertyInfo In info
        Dim value As String = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj)
        If propertyInfo.PropertyType = GetType(String) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
            ' empty value for this string property
        End If
    Next
End Sub

public Class Test
    Public Property Test As String
End Class
```